# Click on label not working

Tags: javascript

I need to cancel a bunch of orders on a website, because the price is wrong.
There are around 200 in total, so would like to automate this.

Here is the section which I need to address:

```
<div id="orderlist">
<label id="l61">05/14/2014 12:23:17</label>
<label id="l62">0.00000666</label>
<label id="l63">Buy</label>
<label id="l64">1</label>
<label id="l64">1</label>
<label id="l62">6.66E-6000</label>
<label id="l65" onclick="cancelOrder(335210);">Cancel</label>

<div id="b1"></div>
<label id="l61">05/14/2014 12:23:17</label>
<label id="l62">0.00000666</label>
<label id="l63">Buy</label>
<label id="l64">1</label>
<label id="l64">1</label>
<label id="l62">6.66E-6000</label>
<label id="l65" onclick="cancelOrder(335220);">Cancel</label>
```

And so on. div id b1 is a separating line between each order.
What I would need to do is click on label id l65 via a function, or call the onclick function directly.
Problem is that the onclick function's name varies with each order.

I already tried to cancel the top 4 orders in an interval

```
window.setInterval(cancel, 20000);

function cancel(){
    $('#orderlist').find('label:eq(0)').click(l65);
    $('#orderlist').find('label:eq(1)').click(l65);
    $('#orderlist').find('label:eq(2)').click(l65);
    $('#orderlist').find('label:eq(3)').click(l65);
    console.log("running");
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

In the interest on learning more about javascript:

- would it be possible to search for a certain order? EG: only orders with labelid 163 = "Buy", and only delete those?
- How can I get the value of "label l62" of the order where label l63 = "Sell"? If there are multiple orders, I would need the smallest value.

Comment: Why do you expect `.click(l65)` to do? Have you included jQuery on the page? Have you checked http://api.jquery.com/click/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener?

Comment: I was hoping it would only click label l65 respectively in the first four orders.
When I use 'javascript:document.getElementById('l65').click();' , it tries to click them all at once, which crashes the site.

Comment: You mean to say that the function varies with each order. Or you want to say function parameters varies with each order. Also you can check for custom attributes. example data-order='l65' and use this as a object.attr('data-order') in your jquery. Also same ids for multiple elements is not a standard.

Comment: To be clear, the site isn't mine, nor do I have any affiliation to it. I'm just a customer there who needs to cancel a lot of obsolete orders. As stated, using document.getElementById('l65').click() crashes the site, because it wants to press all 200 cancel buttons at once. So if any of you guys could help me with the interval script I tried to implement, I would be very grateful :-)

Comment: You would be able to do it if there is any custom attribute. Or else you have make calls to each function individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help.

```
var clicks = $('#orderlist').find('[onclick]');
```

will find you all the labels with `onclick` inside the orderlist-div.

With

```
$(clicks).each(function(){ ...});
```

you can do your magic then

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d37pC/5/)